# Amazon App Store: I can't publish apps any more

Tags: kindle, amazon-appstore

I've got the problem, that I can not publish amazon apps! I wrote a lot of mails to the support team, but I still got no serious answer.

The problem starts with the new developer console. I'm submitting a new app, the review team writes an email, that my app passed review and is ready for sale, but the app status falls always(!) back to "pending action". But all is okay and nothing can be changed in den developer console. All information circles are green and everything is okay, but the status always(!) falls back to "pending action".

Does anyone have the same problem or better have a solution? The Amazon App team seems to be unable to fix that problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Amazon developer support.

Comment: Hmm, my question is: has anyone the same problems with the App status and maybe some solution.

Comment: What is the name of the app you are trying to submit? If you are comfortable disclosing your developer name, that would be helpful. Otherwise, you can reach me on twitter @MikeFHines (we can DM).